# How to access containers from external IP?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

I have created kubernetes cluster with one master node and one slave node and deployed containers.How can I access containers through external IP.
I have tried assigning IP address to the containers using type=Loadbalancer in docker compose file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you go through the tutorials for Kubernetes.

In general, (1) you would need 3 master nodes. (2) Setup a Ingress-controller ( HTTP Load balancer ) as a type=LoadBalancer service and then configure Ingress with domain for routing, instead of using IP to access those containers directly.

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/
- https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-101-pods-nodes-containers-and-clusters-c1509e409e16